# Reference for infinite dimensional affine spaces over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request, finite-fields, affine-geometry

I'm reading Hodges's *Model Theory*, and in chapter 4 he mentions a countable-dimensional affine space over $\mathbb{F}_2$. I've worked a bit with finite-dimensional spaces, but I couldn't find any good references on infinite-dimensional spaces, specially over finite fields. Is there any good source for that?

Comment: This is extremely broad.  Can you be more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: @NateEldredge - I was looking for a sort of introduction, which gave basic properties, differences over the more standard cases, etc. Some sort of textbook treatment, I suppose.